# Sstart query and logoff local workstation

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-data-tools, logoff

Is there a way to start running a query (via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) SSMS or SQL Server Data Tools (SSTD)) from your local workstation and then logoff?  I know you could do a remote desktop connection to the server, run the query and then disconnect from the RDP session -- but we are not allowed to do RPD sessions to production servers.  Has anyone used service broker for something like this?  A SQL Server agent job could be created with an EXECUTE SQL task - but I'd like a cleaner solution.

Comment: What you described sounds exactly what a job is.

Comment: I have users who run their own adhoc SQL.  Some of them want to start a query in SSMS - and then logoff for the day - leaving their queries running.  These people don't have authority to create jobs.

Comment: Well you have two competing concerns; SQL Server command must run in context until complete (if the connection is dropped, they are rolled back) and the idea of a user who wants to start a task a logoff.  You need someway to separate these concerns.  Maybe create a job that runs SQL statements in the database itself, then users can add SQL statements and they'll be run by the job (say every 5 minutes).